# entityManager.getTransaction().rollback() detaches entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, entitymanager

I have the following piece of code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test")
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager()
User user = entityManager.find(User.class, 0);
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
entityManager.refresh(user);
```

This throws an IllegalArgumentException on the fourth line saying "Entity not managed". If I change the third line to `.commit()` instead of `.rollback()`, everything seems to work fine.

What is going on here? Can I prevent this from happening?

**UPDATE:** @DataNucleus is directing me towards PersistenceContext. How do I change the persistence context in my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [JSR-000317 Persistence Specification for Eval 2.0 Eval](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/):

> #### 3.3.2 Transaction Rollback
>
> For both transaction-scoped and extended persistence contexts, **transaction rollback causes all pre-existing managed instances and removed instances
>   [31]
>    to become detached**. The instances’ state will be the
>   state of the instances at the point at which the transaction was rolled back. Transaction rollback typically
>   causes the persistence context to be in an inconsistent state at the point of rollback. In particular, the
>   state of version attributes and generated state (e.g., generated primary keys) may be inconsistent.
>   Instances that were formerly managed by the persistence context (including new instances that were
>   made persistent in that transaction) may therefore not be reusable in the same manner as other detached
>   objects—for example, they may fail when passed to the merge operation.
>   [32]

Answer (score 3):

In a PersistenceContext of "Transaction" then commit/rollback will detach objects used in the transaction. In PersistenceContext of "Extended" then commit/rollback do nothing like that, and objects are detached at close of the EM. Depends on your context

Comment: Can you elaborate? How do I change the persistence context?

Comment: Well the JPA spec (section 3.3) would be a good read, but also http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jpa/object_lifecycle.html In DataNucleus we provide a persistence property to allow the user to choose. In standard JPA you default to "extended" for JSE usage, and "transaction" for JEE usage. What Hibernate allows, no idea

Comment: @DataNucleus In JPA 2.0 Spec , it's montioned that rollback cause managed entities of both transaction-scoped and extended persistence context to become detached , check ch. 3.3.2 http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf